# Recommended approach to using CSS in GWT

Tags: css, gwt

With most projects I include a reset-css and then start from scratch with my own CSS styles.

I imagine GWT could be different. What's the recommended approach?

Use one of the 3 offered themes and override as required? Start with another theme?

What have you found works best?

Answer (score 4):

I am a huge fan of [gwtbootstrap.github.com](http://gwtbootstrap.github.com) , a port of the hugely popular Twitter Bootstrap styles and widgets. You can plugin your modified bootstrap theme if you like.

Some advantages :

- If you are strong technical but lousy at making a beautiful user interface, a really professional look is now within reach.
- strong community for Twitter bootstrap
- the widgets/styling are very familiar, end users will feel at home
- easily customizable, themes even commercially available

This is of course a port to GWT and lags a bit.. but the developers are very responsive and helpful.

Comment: Could you provide some details why you are a big fan? And perhaps any negatives you have come across in the projects you've used it with.

Answer (score 2):

I recommend to start with one of the built-in themes. There are a lot of tiny little details you will have to account for (and make sure they work in all browsers) if you start from scratch.

After that the key decision is whether to use an external CSS file, a more traditional approach, or use CSS Resources:
https://developers.google.com/web-toolkit/doc/latest/DevGuideClientBundle#CssResource

CSS Resources offer many nice features, like conditional CSS, runtime substitutions, obfuscation of class names, etc. An external CSS file maybe easier to work with.

For a large project, or any project with multiple developers, I would recommend CSS resources.